# Run kudu fsck in a kerberised CDH cluster

Tags: kerberos, cloudera-cdh, apache-kudu

I am trying to have the cloudera manager run a check on a kudu cluster, which eventually will be the following command, run as the kudu user::

`kudu cluster ksck master_host`

The output of this command is:

> Not authorized: leader master liveness check error: Could not connect to the cluster: Client connection negotiation failed: client connection to 10.x.y.z:7051: server requires authentication, but client does not have Kerberos credentials available

If I run this command manually from the command line, as kudu, I have the same error. If I try to run `kinit`, a password is asked for the kudu user, but as far as I understand it, all the "backend" users are passwordless.

If I update $HOME/.klogin to allow my user with `ksu` I do have a krb ticket (`klist` shows it) but it is still not a ticket for the kudu user, and I end up having the same error message.

My kerberos-fu is weak, but as far as I thought, the cluster was well configured, spark/impala/kudu work well together, without authorisation issue. The inspector is all green, there are kudu credentials for all hosts of the cluster.

How could I have this command run properly from the cloudera manager?

Comment: _"all the 'backend' users are passwordless"_ > wrong. Service accounts store their password in a keytab file. To run commands as a svc account you must `kinit -kt` _`keytab_file`_ _`SPN`_ (usually on the node running the service so that the keytab is already there)

Comment: And of course it's reeeeeally dangerous to juggle with multiple kerberos creds, especially as root, hence setting a temporary env var `KRB5CCNAME` to a "private" cache file is good practise.

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks. I still cannot run ksck from the cloudera manager, but I have found the keytab file indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Half answer:

To run the command in the command line, you can run it from the account of a user who is in the `superuser_acl` setting from kudu. Then as this user run `kinit` and then you can run the `kudu cluster ksck` command.

This does not explain why the same user from cloudera manger still cannot run the rebalance, but at least I have a woarkaround.